# How to load a line of string input from data file into an array

Tags: java

I am complete beginner.  Have a data input file with multiple lines like this

```
name,  number,  number,...
```

I can read the line as a string but need to input the values into an array.  How do I do that.  I've spent 2 days trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check out:

- [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

But particularly, `String.split()`:

```
String list = "first second third";
String[] items = list.split(" "); // = { "first", "second", "third" };
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
String list = "first, second, third";
String[] items = list.split("[ ,]+"); // = { "first", "second", "third" };
```

Then you have things like `StringTokenizer`, which can do it all, e.g.:

```
String values = "name, 1, 2, 3"; 
String name = null;
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value, " ,"); 

if (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) // first token is name
    name = tokenizer.nextToken();
else
    throw new Exception("No name!");

while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) // rest are numbres
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

Or you can do fun stuff with Scanners:

```
String values = "name, 1, 2, 3";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(values);
scanner.useDelimiter("[ ,]+"); // regular expression, 1 or more spaces/commas

String name = null;
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

if (scanner.hasNext()) // first token is name
    name = scanner.next();
else
    throw new Exception("No name!");    

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) // rest are numbers
    numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
```

There's a lot of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned each line has words separated with comma. So you can read the lines and then split the lines to get the array for each line. You may want to add these arrays to another collection such as an ArrayList:

So I am assuming you have the file reading logic and each line you are getting in a string called `line`. You need to put these pieces at the right places in your code:

```
// collection to hold array of words in each line
ArrayList<String[]> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String[]>();

// split your line into an array of words
String wordsInLine[] = line.split("[ ,]+");

// add words array to your collection
listofWords.add(wordsInLine);
```

Comment: You might want to use `[ ,]+` as the `split` pattern, otherwise you will get leading spaces for the OPs input pattern: `name,  number,  number` => { "name", "  number", "  number" }`

Comment: @JasonC yeah thats a good input, accepted :-) But generally i have a habit a of not doing everything for the questioner, leaving some work for him/her ;-)

Comment: I have edited my answer with your input. Also I read your answer, just now, quite detailed, good work!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed sized, so you would have to know how many elements you want to add via a loop. I would recommend using an ArrayList.

This should help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); // instantiating the object
listOfStrings.add(STRING_VARIABLE) // adding onto the ArrayList.
listOfStrings.get(INDEX_NUMBER) // gets the actual String object, using the index number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String strFromFile = "name,number,number,";

if(strFromFile.contains(","))
{
  String[] splitInput = strFromFile.split(",");
String part1 = splitInput[0];  //gives you name
String part2 = splitInput[1]; // gives you number
.....


}
else
{
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + strFromFile + " does not contain ,");
}

List<String[]> finalList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
finalList.add(splitInput);
```

Comment: You could accomplish the same without .contains() by just doing: `String[] splitInput = strFromFile.split(","); if (splitInput.length >= 2) { ... }`